# How do I deal with installing peer dependencies in Angular CLI?

Tags: angular, dependencies, angular-cli, npm-install

I've found myself in an almost endless cycle of errors when trying to update my Angular CLI and NPM. Every time I update, I am met with WARN messages telling me to install peer dependencies (see below), but each time I install a dependency, I am met with more WARN messages. Is there a better way of handling this situation or does it seriously take hours?

```
npm WARN @angular/animations@5.2.1 requires a peer of @angular/core@5.2.1 
but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular/compiler-cli@5.1.0 requires a peer of typescript@>=2.4.2 
<2.6 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@1.0.0-beta.6 requires a peer of 
@angular/core@^4.0.3 but none is installed. You must install peer 
dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@1.0.0-beta.6 requires a peer of 
@angular/common@^4.0.3 but none is installed. You must install peer 
dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@1.0.0-beta.6 requires a peer of 
@angular/forms@^4.0.3 but none is installed. You must install peer 
dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @schematics/angular@0.1.17 requires a peer of @angular-
devkit/core@0.0.29 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies 
yourself.
npm WARN @schematics/angular@0.1.17 requires a peer of @angular-
devkit/schematics@0.0.52 but none is installed. You must install peer 
dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @schematics/schematics@0.0.11 requires a peer of @angular-
devkit/core@0.0.22 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies 
yourself.
npm WARN angular2-notifications@0.7.4 requires a peer of 
@angular/core@^4.0.1 but none is installed. You must install peer 
dependencies yourself.
npm WARN angular2-notifications@0.7.4 requires a peer of 
@angular/common@^4.0.1 but none is installed. You must install peer 
dependencies yourself.
npm WARN angular2-notifications@0.7.4 requires a peer of @angular/platform-
browser@^4.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies 
yourself.
npm WARN angular2-notifications@0.7.4 requires a peer of 
@angular/animations@^4.0.1 but none is installed. You must install peer 
dependencies yourself.
npm WARN bootstrap@4.0.0-beta.2 requires a peer of jquery@1.9.1 - 3 but none 
is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN bootstrap@4.0.0-beta.2 requires a peer of popper.js@^1.12.3 but 
none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN ng2-toasty@4.0.3 requires a peer of @angular/core@^2.4.7 || ^4.0.0 
but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN ngx-carousel@1.3.5 requires a peer of @angular/core@^2.4.0 || 
^4.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN ngx-carousel@1.3.5 requires a peer of @angular/common@^2.4.0 || 
^4.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN tsickle@0.25.5 requires a peer of typescript@>=2.4.2 <2.6 but none 
is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.1.3 
(node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for 
fsevents@1.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: 
{"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
```

I know I must be doing something wrong, but I'm new to Angular.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

Peer dependency warnings, more often than not, can be ignored. The only time you will want to take action is if the peer dependency is missing entirely, or if the version of a peer dependency is higher than the version you have installed.

Let's take this warning as an example:

> npm WARN @angular/animations@5.2.1 requires a peer of
> @angular/core@5.2.1  but none is installed. You must install peer
> dependencies yourself.

With Angular, you would like the versions you are using to be consistent across all packages. If there are any incompatible versions, change the versions in your *package.json*, and run `npm install` so they are all synced up. I tend to keep my versions for Angular at the latest version, but you will need to make sure your versions are consistent for whatever version of Angular you require (which may not be the most recent).

In a situation like this:

> npm WARN ngx-carousel@1.3.5 requires a peer of @angular/core@^2.4.0 ||
> ^4.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies
> yourself.

If you are working with a version of Angular that is higher than 4.0.0, then you will likely have no issues. Nothing to do about this one then. If you are using an Angular version under 2.4.0, then you need to bring your version up. Update the *package.json*, and run `npm install`, or run `npm install` for the specific version you need. Like this:

```
npm install @angular/core@5.2.3 --save
```

You can leave out the `--save` if you are running npm 5.0.0 or higher, that version saves the package in the dependencies section of the *package.json* automatically.

In this situation:

> npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.1.3
> (node_modules\fsevents): npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY:
> Unsupported platform for  fsevents@1.1.3: wanted
> {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current:  {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

You are running Windows, and *fsevent* requires OSX. This warning can be ignored.

Comment: Thanks! Should I update the versions in the "dependencies" and "devDependencies" in my package.json or should I create a "peerDependencies" and add these versions to it?

Comment: My comment about not having to worry about `devDependencies` isn't right. You will want to update version numbers in that section too. The Angular packages in that section should have the same version as the packages in the `dependencies` section. Change the versions there is something that may have to do as well. Sorry for any confusion!

Comment: seems like a task for computers, all the information is in the package.json and my OS  is obvious, it's not fun to learn these. One day people say "our ancestors suffered a lot to get us this point"

Comment: @R.Richards writes "If you are working with a version of Angular that is higher than 4.0.0, then you will likely have no issues." Can the analyzer detect the presence of Angular higher than 4.0.0? If yes, then why show this warning?

Comment: Sorry for being obtuse but I don't get why you get a warning like  ` @angular/core@^2.4.0 || ^4.0.0 but none is installed` if you are working with a version of Angular that is higher than 4.0.0… Is it just because the version is off?

Comment: What if we installed the latest angular version and some of the packages warn like this(There are few libraries I can see this error). While resolving: @dashjoin/json-schema-form@0.8.4
Found: @angular/common@13.2.0
Could not resolve dependency:
peer @angular/common@"~11.2.12" from @dashjoin/json-schema-form@0.8.4

Answer (score 5):

You can ignore the peer dependency warnings by using the --force flag with Angular cli when updating dependencies.

```
ng update @angular/cli @angular/core --force
```

For a full list of options, check the docs: https://angular.io/cli/update

Comment: I would find this answer more helpful if it included a quick explanation of what this does and why it helped you with the issue raised by the OP

Comment: @JTech I've updated my answer, thanks for the feedback.

Comment: using node js command prompt inside clientapp folder , it is working , 
many thanks

Comment: Does it ever cause issues when you `--force` to ignore the dependencies? Is there a flag that can be entered to install all needed dependencies automatically?

Answer (score 1):

Update your angular (globaly):

- by updating with:

> ng update @angular/cli @angular/core

- or remove angular and reinstall it:

> `npm uninstall -g @angular/cli`
> `npm install -g @angular/cli`

After, if you want to use your old angular project (localy):

- Test with `npm list` if some dependencies have changed and get this error:

> npm ERR! peer dep missing: mydependencie, required by somecomponent

it's mean you have to update your project:

- Then you can just, create a new project, paste your code and reinstall all depencies
- Or install all dependencies required by `npm list`:

> `npm install mydependencie`

Answer (score 0):

I found that running the `npm install` command **in the same directory where your Angular project is**, eliminates these warnings. I do not know the reason why.

Specifically, I was trying to use ng2-completer

```
$ npm install ng2-completer --save
npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Work\foo\package.json'
npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Work\foo\package.json'
npm WARN ng2-completer@3.0.3 requires a peer of @angular/common@>= 6.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN ng2-completer@3.0.3 requires a peer of @angular/core@>= 6.0.0 but noneis installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN ng2-completer@3.0.3 requires a peer of @angular/forms@>= 6.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN foo No description
npm WARN foo No repository field.
npm WARN foo No README data
npm WARN foo No license field.
```

I was unable to compile.
When I tried again, this time in my Angular project directory which was in foo/foo_app, it worked fine.

```
cd foo/foo_app
$ npm install ng2-completer --save
```

Answer (score 0):

NPM package libraries have a section in the package.json file named peerDependencies. For example; a library built in Angular 8, will usually list Angular 8 as a dependency.  This is a true dependency for anyone running less than version 8.  But for anyone running version 8, 9 or 10, it's questionable whether any concern should be pursued.

I have been safely ignoring these messages on Angular Updates, but then again we do have Unit and Cypress Tests!

Answer (score 0):

As stated above these warnings can most often be ignored. However, if you have a lot of 3rd party dependencies when trying to upgrade these will often cause issues and will need to be updated as well.

A great resource for this is npm peer which will show you what versions work with each other. Just an FYI as I've been dealing with a bunch of this during an upgrade.