# ngrx/store@6.1.0 requires a peer of @angular/core@^6.0.0 while upgrading to angular 7

Tags: angular, ngrx-store, angular7, peer-dependencies

I tried to migrate Angular 6 application to angular 7 application and have got the following warning messsage

```
npm WARN @ngrx/effects@6.1.0 requires a peer of @angular/core@^6.0.0 but none is installed.
You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @ngrx/store@6.1.0 requires a peer of @angular/core@^6.0.0 but none is installed.
You must install peer dependencies yourself.
```

What does that mean ?

Does it mean that there is no compatible store for angular 7 ?

Will my store not work ?

Comment: The library currently installed during the upgrade is @angular/core 7.0 . Does that mean I need to down grade

Answer (score 7):

**Update:**

NgRx is updated to 6.1.2 to resolve bugs and for compatibility with angular 7.

So according to https://github.com/ngrx/platform/issues/1397, you can ignore the peer dependencies and it should work with angular 7.

**install:**

```
npm install @ngrx/store@6.1.2
```

If you want to get rid of these warning you can go with `@ngrx/store@7` by installing the `Nightly builds` this way:

`npm install github:ngrx/store-builds`

You are required then to have git installed in your system.

But keep in mind that `@ngrx/store@7` still a beta release.

In the above given link, the reason why they apgraded to `NgRx 6.1.2` is that the `@ngrx/router-store` has a bug with angular 7.

**So upgrading to `NgRx 6.1.2` make it usable and compatible with angular 7 and you can ignore the peer dependencies.**

Comment: The library currently installed during the upgrade is @angular/core 7.0 . Does that mean I need to down grade

Comment: Do I need to downgrade the angular/core version to use ngrx. Doesn’t make sense right

Comment: if you need to use `ngrx/store@6.1.0`, then you have to install the required angular core. uninstall your current angular core lib and then install `@angular/core@6.0.0`

Comment: If I install @angular/core@6.0.0 then other packages are affected. Then what’s the use of downgrading all the packages . The basic idea is to upgrade to the latest

Comment: [How do I deal with installing peer dependencies in Angular CLI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48626005/how-do-i-deal-with-installing-peer-dependencies-in-angular-cli/48627003)

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to solve with the following command,

```
 ng update @ngrx/store --next --force
```

Comment: I tried this. I still get the same warning.@ngrx/store@6.1.2 requires a peer of @angular/core@^6.0.0 but none is installed

Comment: use npm install @ngrx/store@6.1.2