# preact-context@1.1.4 requires a peer of preact@^8.2.7 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself

Tags: angular, angular8

When i try to install ngx-movable this warn message will appera in angular.

preact-context@1.1.4 requires a peer of preact@^8.2.7 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I deal with installing peer dependencies in Angular CLI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48626005/how-do-i-deal-with-installing-peer-dependencies-in-angular-cli)