# Azure Devops - Deployng React Application - Error - ENOENT: no such file or directory, symlink '../detect-port-alt/bin/detect-port'

Tags: reactjs, azure-devops

Suddenly, my CI stopped with a series of errors, I`m using Azure DevOps with Azure Web App Linux.
I`m getting several errors, and I can't figure out this:

> ### [error]npm WARN bootstrap@4.4.1 requires a peer of jquery@1.9.1 - 3 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
>
> npm WARN react-id-swiper@2.4.0 requires a peer of swiper@>=5.0.0 but
>   none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
>
> npm ERR! code ENOENT npm ERR! syscall symlink npm ERR! path
>   ../detect-port-alt/bin/detect-port npm ERR! dest
>   /home/site/wwwroot/node_modules/.bin/detect npm ERR! errno -2 npm ERR!
>   enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, symlink
>   '../detect-port-alt/bin/detect-port' ->
>   '/home/site/wwwroot/node_modules/.bin/detect' npm ERR! enoent This is
>   related to npm not being able to find a file. npm ERR! enoent
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
>   /home/.npm/_logs/2019-12-12T03_04_50_583Z-debug.log npm WARN
>   @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@1.6.0 requires a peer of typescript@*
>   but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
>   npm WARN @typescript-eslint/parser@1.6.0 requires a peer of
>   typescript@* but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies
>   yourself. npm WARN @typescript-eslint/typescript-estree@1.6.0 requires
>   a peer of typescript@* but none is installed. You must install peer
>   dependencies yourself. npm WARN react-id-swiper@2.4.0 requires a peer
>   of swiper@>=5.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer
>   dependencies yourself. npm WARN tsutils@3.17.1 requires a peer of
>   typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev ||
>
> > = 3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
>
> npm ERR! code ENOENT npm ERR! syscall symlink npm ERR! path
>   ../detect-port-alt/bin/detect-port npm ERR! dest
>   /home/site/wwwroot/node_modules/.bin/detect npm ERR! errno -2 npm ERR!
>   enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, symlink
>   '../detect-port-alt/bin/detect-port' ->
>   '/home/site/wwwroot/node_modules/.bin/detect' npm ERR! enoent This is
>   related to npm not being able to find a file. npm ERR! enoent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The peer dependencies missing error can be caused by incompatible dependencies(version of a peer dependency is higher than the version you have installed). You may need to run npm install in your pipeline to install and update your dependencies.

```
- script: npm install
```

or

```
- task: Npm@1
  inputs:
    command: 'install'
```

You can also have a try installing each of the miss peer dependencies with its correct version in your pipeline.

```
- script: |
    npm install -g jquery@1.9.1 --save
    npm install -g swiper@>=5.0.0 --save
    ...
```

You can check this [similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48626005/how-do-i-deal-with-installing-peer-dependencies-in-angular-cli/48627003) for more information. For building react.js example you can refer to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/javascript?view=azure-devops#react-and-vue).