# Npm Angular Warning while installing packages

Tags: angular, npm, angular-cli, npm-install

I am getting npm warnings when I am trying to install packages:

```
$ npm install
npm WARN @angular/compiler-cli@10.0.2 requires a peer of @angular/compiler@10.0.2 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

audited 1595 packages in 18.719s

58 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 294 low severity vulnerabilities
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
```

In order to address the above peer issue warning, I tried installing that peer dependency and get the following warnings:

```
$ npm install @angular/compiler@10.0.2
npm WARN @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@8.2.14 requires a peer of @angular/compiler@8.2.14 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN codelyzer@5.2.1 requires a peer of @angular/compiler@>=2.3.1 <10.0.0 || >9.0.0-beta <10.0.0 || >9.1.0-beta <10.0.0 || >9.2.0-beta <10.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

+ @angular/compiler@10.0.2
added 1 package from 1 contributor, updated 1 package and audited 1596 packages in 15.701s

58 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 294 low severity vulnerabilities
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I deal with installing peer dependencies in Angular CLI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48626005/how-do-i-deal-with-installing-peer-dependencies-in-angular-cli)

Comment: Nope that doesn't help. As it keeps giving same error if I switch   and install @angular/compiler@10.0.2 or 8.2.14

Answer (score 0):

Your package.json would not have `@angular/compiler@10.0.2`
Some libraries are dependent on others in the world of node packages like in this case `@angular/compiler-cli@10.0.2` is dependent or uses some functionalities of `@angular/compiler@10.0.2`.

**Just add `@angular/compiler@10^` to your `package.json` and you will not get the warning next time you run npm install**

Comment: it does have that in package.json:
"devDependencies":  {
   "@angular/compiler": "^10.0.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^10.0.2",}